# How much should I know about Hibernate before I add it to my CV/Resume?

Tags: resume, hibernate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [At which point do you “know” a technology enough to list it on a resume](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/15004/at-which-point-do-you-know-a-technology-enough-to-list-it-on-a-resume)

I have been holding off adding Hibernate to my CV (resume, for American readers),but we are just coming to the end of a project where we have used it successfully and it might be time to add it. I don't know if we covered all the usual parts of this product, because it was my first such project.

Could someone come up with a list of the major features, without knowledge of such, I would come to grief in a hypothetical job interview?